# Não estou conseguindo abrir um byte array extraído do banco!

Tags: c#, postgresql, blob

Linguagem: C#/ASP.NET

Banco de dados: PostgreeSQL

Componente utilizado para upload do arquivo: FileUpload

---

Segue abaixo o componente:

[image: fileUpload]

Segue abaixo o método para efetuar a inserção a uma tabela no banco que só possui os campos:

id_anexo / nome_anexo / anexo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E por fim o método para abrir o arquivo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o resultado deste método é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste exemplo eu fiz o upload de uma imagem .jpg e me deu este erro de resultado. Eu não estou conseguindo recuperar nenhum arquivo.

O que tem de errado com meus métodos, ainda não consegui visualizar... Grato.

Comment: Se você está abrindo um arquivo, por que está usando `File.WriteAllBytes()`? Não seria o caso de ler o arquivo, e não escrever?

Comment: Acho que não. Eu já tenho este arquivo dentro do meu banco de dados em Bytea(Byte[]) o que eu quero agora é escreve-lo novamente (transforma-lo de byte[] pra .jpg) para abrir.

Answer (score 1):

O problema ocorre porque você não está gravando corretamente o conteúdo do arquivo.

Pelo seu código, a propriedade *Anexo* da classe **AnexoBLL** é do typo *byte[]*. No ponto do código que você cria a string SQL que será executada no banco de dados, você está simplesmente concatenando a propriedade do tipo byte[] com uma string. Isso não fará com que o valor da propridade seja utilizado, mas o framework irá utilizar internamente o método .ToString() do tipo byte[], o que fará com que seja retornado o nome do tipo. Logo a sua query ficaria algo parecido com:

```
insert into tb_anexo (nome_arquivo, anexo) values ('imagem.jpg', 'System.Byte[]')
```

O correto seria a utilização de parâmetros, não só para que o código funcione, mas porque é uma boa prática e evita até mesmo problemas de segurança (SQL injection). Para inserir, utilize o código como a seguir (adapte para utilizar a sua conexão):

```
Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand command = new Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand();
command.CommandText = "insert into tb_anexo (nome_arquivo, anexo) values (:nome_arquivo, :anexo)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("nome_arquivo", anexo.NomeArquivo);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("anexo",NpgsqlDbType.Bytea, anexo.Arquivo);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Estou supondo que você está utilizando o tipo correto na sua coluna, que neste caso deve ser **bytea** (veja mais em http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-binary.html)

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo seu esclarecimento Marcus! Eu já tinha até mudado o código antes de ver sua postagem pra este modo, mas foi bom saber que é uma boa prática. Porém meu problema agora é que eu não estou conseguindo recuperar este bytea do banco. Quando eu tento recuperar ele me retorna nulo. Pode me ajudar/

Comment: Quando você executa a query direto no banco, o que você vê? A coluna anexo está com o valor null ou não? Você poderia mostrar o código que faz a leitura da tabela? Está usando DataReader?